# Trouble With Parallel Period and Simple Moving Average

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am trying to calculate the simple moving average for a year previous to the data set I am examining.

I have the following query which gives me an SMA as of week 35 of 2016 (`201635`) for students starting in term `2016 5a`, `2016 5b`, `2016 1`.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[LY Enrolments 10 Week SMA] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Enrolments 10 Week SMA]
     ,ParallelPeriod
      (
        [Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Calendar].[ISO Year]
       ,1
       ,[Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Calendar].[ISO Week].&[201535]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Enrolments]
     ,[Measures].[Enrolments 10 Week SMA]
     ,[Measures].[LY Enrolments 10 Week SMA]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Term Enrolments].[Terms].[Term Hierarchy].&[2016]&[5a]
     ,[Term Enrolments].[Terms].[Term Hierarchy].&[2016]&[5b]
     ,[Term Enrolments].[Terms].[Term Hierarchy].&[2017]&[1]
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Enrolments]
WHERE 
  (
    [Term Enrolments].[Cancelled].&[No]
   ,[Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Calendar].[ISO Week].&[201635]
  );
```

I would like to also place alongside this the SMA for week 35 of 2015 for terms `2015 5a`, `2015 5b`, `2016 1`. This is what I am trying to get in the member calculation, but nothing is happening.

How can I get a comparison of the SMAs between years? How do I compare to members of the `Term Hierarchy` one year previous?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing this `[Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Calendar].[ISO Week].&[201535]` for this `[Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER`.

Hopefully the `CURRENTMEMBER` function will pick up the week specified in the `WHERE` clause. I will try to test against AdvWrks as a little unsure.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[LY Enrolments 10 Week SMA] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Enrolments 10 Week SMA]
     ,ParallelPeriod
      (
        [Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Calendar].[ISO Year]
       ,1
       ,[Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Enrolments]
     ,[Measures].[Enrolments 10 Week SMA]
     ,[Measures].[LY Enrolments 10 Week SMA]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Term Enrolments].[Terms].[Term Hierarchy].&[2016]&[5a]
     ,[Term Enrolments].[Terms].[Term Hierarchy].&[2016]&[5b]
     ,[Term Enrolments].[Terms].[Term Hierarchy].&[2017]&[1]
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Enrolments]
WHERE 
  (
    [Term Enrolments].[Cancelled].&[No]
   ,[Term Record Creation].[ISO Week Calendar].[ISO Week].&[201635]
  );
```

Tested and this works for me ok:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount LY] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
     ,[Date].[Calendar Weeks].[Calendar Week].&[27]&[2007]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount LY2] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
     ,ParallelPeriod
      (
        [Date].[Calendar Weeks].[Calendar Year]
       ,1
       ,[Date].[Calendar Weeks].CurrentMember
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount LY]
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount LY2]
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Product].[Product Categories].[Category].[Accessories]
     ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].[Bikes]
     ,[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].[Clothing]
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Date].[Calendar Weeks].[Calendar Week].&[27]&[2008];
```

Results in the following:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't fixed my problem. I still get no result column for my SMA measure.